# Cuneiform in WinEdt

Tags: xetex, pdftex, winedt

What's wrong with this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontface{\cuneiform}[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Santakku}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcuneiform}{\cuneiform}

\newcommand{\KA}{\symbol{"12157}}

\begin{document}

This is cuneiform \textcuneiform{\KA}.


\end{document}
```

Command Line:   D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\miktex\bin\x64\xelatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "unic.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\hynek0\Desktop\TH0dipl

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.7050 64-bit)
entering extended mode
(unic.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/base\article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/base\size10.clo))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/l3packages/xparse\xparse.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/l3kernel\expl3-code.tex)
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-xdvipdfmx.def)))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec-xetex.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/base\tuenc.def))
(D:\ProgramFiles\MikTexNEW\tex/latex/fontspec\fontspec.cfg)))Running miktex-makemf.exe...


 Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed.
```

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

C:\Users\hynek0\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log

```
Running miktex-hbf2gf.exe...


hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4)



Couldn't open `Santak.cfg'


Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed.
```

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

C:\Users\hynek0\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-maketfm.log

```
! Package fontspec Error: The font "Santakku" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.6 \DeclareTextFontCommand
                           {\textcuneiform}{\cuneiform}
? 

Process has been terminated ...
```

Comment: Compiles OK for me. Is the font installed in your system folder?

Comment: @Cicada NO it isn't. I'm a beginner and I do not know HOW and from WHERE to isntall it. Could you please give me a hint?  I now have a zip file from [Here](https://ctan.org/pkg/cun) cun.zip. What should I do next? I have Win 8.1 and WinEdt 10.3

Comment: @Cicada I have now even Santakku.ttf but I do not know where to place it?

Comment: @Cicada I have just double clicked on ttf file and it has installed. But the result is not the same as in the book Unicode 5.0 see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510246/the-character-from-unicode-5-0-book-is-not-the-same-as-result-from-xetex-with-wi)

Comment: Unicode chart shows the Classical Sumerian shapes; the characters written a thousand years later "are considered font variants" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuneiform_(Unicode_block)