# the character from Unicode 5.0 book is not the same as result from XeTeX with WinEdt 10.3

Tags: fonts, xetex, winedt

I've donwloaded this ttf file [here](http://www.hethport.uni-wuerzburg.de/cuneifont/download/Santakku.zip) and install it 
BUT the following code doesn't give the same result (given below the snippet prefaced with "This is cuneiform" ) as in the snippet below from the book UNICODE 5.0

**Code:**

```
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontface{\cuneiform}[Scale=MatchUppercase]{Santakku}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcuneiform}{\cuneiform}

\newcommand{\AN}{\symbol{"1202F}}
\newcommand{\KA}{\symbol{"12136}}

\begin{document}

This is cuneiform \textcuneiform{\AN\KA}.


\end{document}
```

[image]

**The result**

[image]

Comment: Santakku is Old Babylonian (https://www.hethport.uni-wuerzburg.de/cuneifont/). The shapes in the unicode chart are not prescriptive. Three stars AN is available in Noto Sans Cuneiform, Akkadian, and a few others.

Comment: (http://www.sumerisches-glossar.de/download/SignListNeoAssyrian.pdf) has the NeoAssyrian shapes. Did you want to study Sumerian?

Comment: Unrelated to the question: Unicode is up to version 12.1 now. The shapes are still not prescriptive. "Considerable variation is to be expected in actual fonts."